# Watson Assistant - entity reference in Intents - I need to understand what I'm missing

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm using watson assistant (plus) and I'm actually fighting with the correct usage of entity usage inside intent examples. First of all, inside the webUI I can't find trace of what mentioned in the documentation about entity suggestions, entity annotation inside intents examples..(we are on frankfurt server).

I have many intents in one skill and I decided to use entity mentions in intents examples. Having no trace of simplified way to add entity inside the single example, I directly wrote it inside the phrase.
From "What I need to activate MySpecificService ABC ?" to "What I need to activate @services:(MySpecificService ABC)", the same syntax used in dialog nodes.
I have used this method diffusely on my skill, according the documentation.

My problems starts here. Assistant refuse to detect the right intent when I try it.
If I ask "What I need to activate MyService Name?" the assistant detect a totally wrong intent, with low confidence (0.40 or less), and the correct intent does not appear neither as 2nd or 3rd intent (it correctly detect the entity).
No similar examples using exaclty @services:(MySpecificService ABC) in other intents, but I used other references to @services or @services:(otherservice name) in other intents.

I read documentation many times, I googled around, watched videos.. but nothing. Evidently I've misunderstood something.
Can You help me?

Answer (score 0):

Intents are the actions/verbs that the user is trying to achieve. In this case, an intent could be the activation itself (no matter what is he trying to activate).
So you should write different examples of an activation question: 
"How can I activate my service?", "I need to activate this service", etc.
The entities are the objects/substantives. In your case, services.

So in your dialog, if you are need the assistant to detect the intent+entity. So create a node with the condition `#activation && @service:MySpecificService`

Be aware that if you have several nodes in your dialog, their order will impact the way that your assistant analyzes the input. If the `#activation && @service` node is before the `#activation && @service:MySpecificService` node; the first one will be triggered as "MySpecificService" is one of the @services.

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

im dealing with entities in intents as well and i think we're also on the frankfurt server.

Since youre on the frankfurt server im pretty sure the reason youre not seeing the annotation options is that youre using german language.

Annotations as mentioned in the documentation is only available for english language (unfortunately)

kr

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment. An answer should be how do deal with it. The question was not why annotations are not working, but rather how to do it. In addition, you need to provide a link to the documentation.

Comment: However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege gained from earning reputation - if you haven't earned it yet, try to get comfortable writing answers first.

Therefore i was only left with answer ;)